# SQL Server 2012 - Can't detach database on mirror server

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I'm running SQL Server 2012 in a mirror configuration and I need to move the mirror's transaction files.

I deleted the mirror setup on the primary but I can't detach the databases on the mirror, the option is grayed out.

I used activity monitor and the database files are NOT being used so I should be able to detach the databases. Does anybody have any clues as to what the hold up is?

Thank you.

Comment: And how you deleted mirror configuration ?. I am sure you did it in wrong way

Comment: I opened SQL Management Studio on primary, tasks -> Mirror, choose "delete Mirror". What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

To remove [database mirroring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190471.aspx#TsqlProcedure)

1. Connect to the Database Engine of either mirroring partner.
2. From the Standard bar, click New Query.
3. Issue the following Transact-SQL statement:

`ALTER DATABASE database_name SET PARTNER OFF`

where database_name is the mirrored database whose session you want to remove.

The following example removes database mirroring from the AdventureWorks2012 sample database.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET PARTNER OFF;
```